# Auto generated graph from one large excel file

Tags: excel, vba, graph, auto-generate

I am trying to create auto generated charts in excel. I need to create 50 charts originated from one excel table. There is an unique id for each chart.

What I am looking for is when I click the Unique id in Column B(e.g. ASD) the chart will pop up displaying the Sections(column) Vs. Year for the selected unique id. Below I have pasted an example chart for convenience. I am not good at programming. I really need your help. I will really appreciate if you please help me out here. Thanks

[Example Graph of Number OF TEACHER VS CLASSES & FEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GqkR.png)
[Example Table for Creating Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldfTI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a helper sheet, I place in it the formulas to gather the data required to be used in a chart typically using SUMIFS(), COUNTIFS(), VLOOKUP(), etc.

Alternatively if I'm doing a larger BI spreadsheet I will use ListObjects (tables) and define names in the Name Manager using a combination of OFFSET, MATCH, VLOOKUP, etc to automatically return a range of values from the ListOjects and then reference these in the chart/s.

Whichever of the two above options you use we can update the target Unique ID by using the following VBA, note the workbook will need to be saved as a Macro Enabled Workbook. This code will update Cell A1 in the HelperSheet which we will use to update the data for the chart;

- Go to VBA (F11)
- Open the code base for the sheet which holds your IDs.
- Add the below code.

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim varIntersects As Variant
      'Change Columns(1) to match your ID column.
      Set varIntersects = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.Columns(1).EntireColumn)
      If Application.Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
          If Not varIntersects Is Nothing Then
              If Not Selection.Value = "" Then
                  'Change HelperSheet and A1 to suit your needs.
                  Worksheets("HelperSheet").Range("A1") = Selection.Cells.Value
              End If
          End If
      End If
  End Sub
  ```